# Java cannot find Symbol - containsKey(Item)?

Tags: java, hashmap, key, containskey

In my Supermarket Checkout Program when I run it, it comes up with this error in the `Checkout` class in the `addItem` method:

> cannot find symbol - method containsKey(Item)

I cannot understand why it is coming up with this error as I have checked the other two classes (`Item` and `Stock`) and I can't see anything wrong with them.

Here are the classes:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Checkout {
    private HashMap<Item, Integer> stock;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Checkout. Instantiates the checkout.
     */
    public Checkout() {
        stock = new HashMap<Item, Integer>();
    }


    public void addItem(String itemCode) {
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        if (stock.containsSalesItem(itemCode)) {
            Item item = stock.getItem(itemCode);

            int quantity = 1;
            if (stock.containsKey(item)) {
                Integer quantity = stock.get(item);
                quantity += quantity.intValue();
            }
            stock.put(item, new Integer(quantity));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Item {
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private int price;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Item
     */
    public Item(String itemName, String itemCode, int costOfItem) {
        name = itemName;
        price = costOfItem;
        code = itemCode;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

}
```

---

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Stock {
    private static Map<String, Item> stock;

    static {
        stock = new HashMap<String, Item>();
        stock.put("001", new Item("Diet Coke 1l Bottle", "001", 299));
        stock.put("002", new Item("Haribo", "002", 100));
        stock.put("003", new Item("Digestive Biscuits", "003", 120));
        stock.put("004", new Item("Teacakes", "004", 80));
        stock.put("005", new Item("Bacon", "005", 399));
        stock.put("006", new Item("Bread", "006", 213));
    }

    public Collection<Item> getItems() {
        return stock.values();
    }

    public Item getItem(String itemCode) {
        return stock.get(itemCode);
    }

    public boolean containsSalesItem(String itemCode) {
        if (stock.containsKey(itemCode)) {
            return stock.containsKey(itemCode);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: Does your `Stock` class have a `containsKey` method?

Comment: yes its the containsSalesItem (String itemCode) method in that class?

Comment: What? `containsSalesItem` and `containsKey`... Do you not see a difference?

Comment: I have now changed it so it has containsKey instead of containsSalesItems, but now I have another problem as in the stock class still with the same method it comes up with an error on this:       if (stock.containsKey(item)) - item cannot be converted to java.lang.string

Comment: if (stock.containsKey(item)) - item cannot be converted to java.lang.string

Answer (score 1):

Your `Stock` class doesn't have a `containsKey()` method

Comment: It did have a containsKey method  but it was named incorrectly (containsSalesItems), I have changed it to containsKey(). But now I have another error that I have listed above